# ReSharper warning about ClosureOnModifiedVariable - why?

Tags: javascript, scope, warnings, resharper

So I came upon this code during a review:

```
        var permissions = $("#" + me.map.permissionsGridHtmlId).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
        var data = form.serializeArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            var record = permissions[i].toJSON();
            $.each(record, function (key, value) {
                data.push({
                    // ReSharper disable once ClosureOnModifiedVariable
                    name: "Permissions[" + i + "]." + key,
                    value: value
                });
            });
        }
```

and that '// ReSharper disable' comment gave me pause.
I tried to look into it, and found this - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/AccessToForEachVariableInClosure.html

However, I tried to remove the comment and then do as that link said, create a variable inside of the scope to store the value, but the warning didn't go away.

Furthermore, despite the warning, it seems to behave as designed - the value of 'i' changes properly, and at the end the 'data' variable stores the proper/expected values.

So, my question is... why is ReSharper warning about this? Is there an actual problem in the code, or a bug in ReSharper? If the former, how should I fix the code? If the latter, is this warning *ever* right (and so we should leave the disable comment) or should I change the inspection severity to never show this warning?

### Update

The following change to the code made the warning go away:

```
        $.each(permissions, function (i, permission) {
            $.each(permission.toJSON(), function (key, value) {
                data.push({
                    name: "Permissions[" + i + "]." + key,
                    value: value
                });
            });
        });
```

I'd still like to know *why* the warning exists, though, when the two code snippets appear to act identically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to modified closure is only a problem if a lambda (function parameter in your case) would be executed after variable modification. In your case, `$.each` should execute lambda instantly, so it shouldn't be a problem. But ReSharper doesn't know if a called function would execute a passed lambda instantly or would store it for later execution, especially in JavaScript with its dynamic typing. So it just gives the warning always.

Please note that the article you found refers to C#, and the fix it suggests is only valid for C#. You cannot fix a problem in JS by using `var i1 = i`, because variable `i1` declared by `var` would have a function scope, and you need it to have a block scope. So, if you can use ECMAScript 2015, then you can use `let` or `const` to declare a variable with a block scope, for example:

```
var permissions = $("#" + me.map.permissionsGridHtmlId).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
var data = form.serializeArray();
for (var i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
    var record = permissions[i].toJSON();
    let i1 = i;
    $.each(record, function (key, value) {
        data.push({
            name: "Permissions[" + i1 + "]." + key,
            value: value
        });
    });
}
```